# Adding comments to columns

Tags: mysql, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alter MYSQL Table To Add Comments on Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns)

Hi Guys,

I googled all over the place but I can't find the answer. I know you can add comments to your database columns. I already created a table but now i want to add comments to certain columns, my database programma (sequel pro) doesn't have a function to alter the columns with comments.

Is there an 'update' or 'alter' query to add comments to your columns? The database is in mysql.

Thanks!

UPDATE: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns). Now Trying if it's working

Comment: The other question was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
COMMENT "comment"
```

after your

```
ALTER TABLE xxx CHANGE xxx...
```