# Adding comments to all columns of an existing table

Tags: mysql, alter-table

Please suggest how to add comments to all columns of an existing table in database?

for eg: 
i have a table Employee with columns
emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary, emp_address.

Now, i want to add comments to each column of the table.

Please suggest how to achieve it in one command.

Saw a duplicate thread:
[Alter MySQL table to add comments on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns)

But the suggested reply could not be understood!

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain why you don't understand the answer, as it does indeed seem to answer your question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alter MYSQL Table To Add Comments on Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns)

Comment: Can you give your table schema so we can help perfectly

Comment: could not understand this:
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) COMMENT 'id of user'
Please let me know what 'id' 'id'  means

Comment: the first `id` indicates the field that is altered, the second `id` stands for the new name. In this example the name remains the same, thus the `id` `id`.

Answer (score 3):

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee 
  MODIFY fieldname new_fieldname INT(11) COMMENT 'the comment you want to add',
  MODIFY fieldname2 new_fieldname2 INT(11) COMMENT 'comment for the seconds row',
  MODIFY fieldname3 new_fieldname3 INT(11) COMMENT 'comment for third row';
```

Note that you have to include the column definition again when adding the comment.

Comment: hi thanks, but how do i add comments to all column at once?
I mean to say, i have columns emp_id, emp_name, emp_salary, emp_address i want to add comments for all columns with a single command.

Comment: see edits. modify statements must be comma separated, and then add a `;` after the last one

Comment: it did not work, in pl/sql i get error: ora-01735 invalid ALTER TABLE option.