# TRUNCATE all tables matching name pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

This is the sql i'm using based from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22608575/6950515) answer:

```
SET @pattern = '%_movielist';

SELECT concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(concat(TABLE_NAME)), ';')
INTO @truncatelike FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @pattern;

SELECT @truncatelike;

PREPARE stmt FROM @truncatelike;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but I get this error `Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'`.
What am I doing wrong? It seems to work for other users

Comment: on which database are you trying to execute this statement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484722/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-while-attempting-to-grant-privileges

Comment: @teodore-vecerdi Please refer may answer below.

Comment: @ankit-agrawal Why do you want the user to grant access to the information_schema database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying to execute this statement on **"information_schema"**  database. Read more about this database [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html]

You should not be running statements on the information_schema database (unless you REALLY know what you're doing). The database serves as a "meta" repository that dictates how the server operates. Chances are that you have no need to touch it and you'll likely brick your server if you do.

This is already answered here. [[#1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912394/1044-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-to-database-information-schem])

**Restriction to above:** This query will work only if the no of table returned by the statement is 1 for more than 1 tables, you will require to use it in iteration.

**To make this work for all the table matching the pattern we would require to use stored procedure.**

**Please change the Procedure name**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
-- Pattern to Match 
SET @pattern = '%_movielist';
-- Temporary Table to Store the Result of The Select Statement

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table_ToBeTruncated 
    (
       Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,TableName varchar(100),
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );

-- Insert all the TableName  to be Truncated 
    insert Table_ToBeTruncated(TableName)
    SELECT distinct concat('TRUNCATE TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '`;')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE @pattern and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'movielist';

-- Declare a variable to count the no of records to be truncated.
SET @count=(Select count(*)from Table_ToBeTruncated);

-- Iterate the list 
WHILE @count> 0 DO

    -- Pick One table from the Temporary Table List;
    SELECT TableName into @truncatelike from Table_ToBeTruncated where ID= @count;

    -- Prepare the statement
    PREPARE stmt FROM @truncatelike;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    -- Decrease the counter.
    set @count = @count- 1;

END WHILE;

drop TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Table_ToBeTruncated ;

END
```

Comment: Okay, so if I can't run statements on information_schema, then how can I truncate all the tables in my other database which name matches the pattern?

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi Use the query in the database that contains the tables which are required to be truncated.

Comment: but the database that contains the tables doesn't have a "TABLES" table like information_schema

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi   information_schema is not a table, it's a database which serves as a "meta" repository that dictates how the server operates. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know, I was reffering to the TABLES table in information_schema. Also, I'm a beginner with SQL so I don't really know how to do advanced things

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi No worries, welcome here, we are happy to help, let us know if you are facing issues.

Comment: I still don't know how to truncate all the tables from my database whose name match a pattern.

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi No Problem I will have a answer created for you.

Comment: Thank you, the db name is "movielist" and I need the pattern to be "%_movielist"

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi I have prepared the answer if this works for you, please feel free to flag and mark the answer as accepted. This will help other looking for similar solution.

Comment: Should I replace the definer with something like 'root'@'%'?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi You can ignore the definer and proceed it optional. Will update you on definer in a while.

Comment: [here](https://i.imgur.com/ZnmGN6N.png). The SQL code is the same as you provided. I only changed the procedure name. Line 4 is `SET @pattern = '%_movielist'`

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi  Which tool are you using explore table and database structure, or doing it through console.

Comment: I'm using phpmyadmin

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi this video might be helpful for you [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn-f2I7Sb88 ]creating stored procedure in phpmyadmin . If you still face issues, my skype id is "rimrohit" where we can share the screen solve at earliest.

Comment: So I just ran the sql code you provided from Jetbrains' DataGrip and it worked xD. Thank you so much man!

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi I wished I could have solved it more quickly If you found my answer, would appreciate if you mark it useful and accepted so that it could be helpful for others too. It was nice working with you cheer! Reach us if any help required.

Comment: @TeodorVecerdi Thanks for letting me know another provider  Jetbrains' DataGrip ...