# Can column comment be a utf-8 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, comments, alter-table

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns) is quetions about adding comment to column for MySQL. Can this comment be utf-8? Also what encoding MySQL uses for these columns by default?

Answer (score 1):

Default character set and collation is set when the database is created

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You can modify character set on a specific column like this

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```