# How to safely modify a lot of MySQL column comments?

Tags: mysql, database, schema, database-schema

In our current database, We have a lot of tables without a comment on the column. We would like to add comments to columns, but

```
 ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) COMMENT 'id of user'
```

will change the column data schema,too.

We are afraid that with so many changes, a mistake would be made and the data schema would be accidentally altered.

What would be the best way to insert the comments with no change to the data schema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script creates the required `ALTER TABLE` statements. After running it, change the comments descriptions, then run those `ALTER TABLE` statements.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17791564/378779

Comment: ok,thank you. the script is the a good way to do such dangerous thing

Comment: @SaiSai If this post answers your question, please mark it as such, thanks!