# Adding comments to table column which is used as foreign key in another table(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add comments to columns for already created **users** table in MySQL database

I am trying following command

```sql
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE id id INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'id of user';
```

But I am getting following error as the id column is used as foreign key in **user_address** table

```sql
SQL Error [1833] [HY000]: Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'user_address_users_FK' of table 'user_address'
```

How to do add comment to id column without getting this error? Also is there a way to add comment without a need to mention column definition again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alter MySQL table to add comments on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns)

Comment: Post truncated (remove unrelated fields/indices) DDL of both tables.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` column of the `users` table is a `AUTO_INREMENT` column right?

If you don't specify the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the `ALTER TABLE`, MySQL removes the `AUTO_INCREMENT` on the column `id`. So you have to add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` to the `ALTER TABLE` command too:

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id of user';
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=392f2930617e30d486231f4ef77f9ce7)

Comment: ok but is there a way to do it without requiring to define column again

Comment: No you have to define the column again.