# Mysql:how to change table comment after created already?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

How to do it with mysql-cli? `table comment` means for example `foo` below:

```
create table t (c1 int) comment='foo';
```

Comment: Check if this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns

Comment: @JoseLora that's about adding comments to columns. This question is about changing comments on tables.

Answer (score 3):

you can use
mysql> alter table t comment='f1';
mysql> commit;

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: As it turns out there is an `alter` statement that allows to change `table` comments. As Dogs Cute pointed out, this command actually works:

```
alter table t comment='f1';
```

**Below we see a way one can change a table definition if there is no way to perform a change with alter. It was applied for comment change, but, as Dogs Cute has pointed out, it's unnecessary for this scenario, but it may be useful for some other scenarios.**

As far as I know it is impossible to achieve that with an alter. Instead, I would do the following:

## Step 1: Find out the definition of the table

Run

```
show create table t;
```

and save the result somewhere (clipboard or file, whatever)

## Step 2: Create a similar table

Run

```
create table t_temp ...
```

(where ... is the continuation of the command, do not take that literally, see **Step 1**)

## Step 3: Copy your data to the temp table

Run

```
insert into t_temp(...)
select ...
from t;
```

where `...` represents the column list. Again, do not take this literally.

## Step 4: Drop the current table

Run

```
drop table t;
```

## Step 5: Rename the temp table

```
alter table t_temp rename t;
```

## Final note

I **strongly** recommend that you back up your database regularly and specifically before you do such large changes to avoid irreparable data-loss.

Comment: Thanks for answering.i'm new in mysql, so i wonder what's the difference between this way and `alter table t comment='f1';`

Comment: @user15320797 Please accept Dogs Cute's answer. It shows an alter command that actually changes the comment on a table. I tested it and it works. My initial answer assumed that the alter command does not support this feature and has shown an alternative approach by creating a copy of the table with the new comment, moving all the data and removing the original table. It uses a lot of storage space, memory and time if you have millions of records, so the simple alter command that Dogs Cute suggested should be preferred over the solution I originally proposed. I have edited my answer as well

Comment: in order to make sure that it contains this information.

Answer (score 0):

> Check if this answers your question. [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162420/alter-mysql-table-to-add-comments-on-columns)

thanks. @JoseLora